# OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation (pytesseract.image_to_string)

Tags: python, python-tesseract, elevation, oserror

I am having a simple code that has an image called "1.png" and I want to convert it from Image to Text using pytesseract. but, I am having some issues with the code.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread('1.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd =r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

### But it's giving me an error.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15096/3527021470.py in <module>
----> 1 result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, output_type, timeout)
    411     """
    412     args = [image, 'txt', lang, config, nice, timeout]
--> 413 
    414     return {
    415         Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in <lambda>()
    414     return {
    415         Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
--> 416         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
    417         Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    418     }[output_type]()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    282             'timeout': timeout,
    283         }
--> 284 
    285         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    286         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + extsep + extension

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    253         proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
    254     except OSError as e:
--> 255         if e.errno != ENOENT:
    256             raise e
    257         raise TesseractNotFoundError()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    250         cmd_args.append(extension)
    251 
--> 252     try:
    253         proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
    254     except OSError as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    856                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    857 
--> 858             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
    860                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1309             # Start the process
   1310             try:
-> 1311                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1312                                          # no special security
   1313                                          None, None,

OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

Any idea on how to overcome this error. Please help me to rectify it

1. I have downloaded .exe file from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and executed it.
2. tesseract.exe file which is present inside "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" is set to Run this program as Administrator
3. pytesseract Version: 0.3.8
4. I have added "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR" to Environmental Variable

Comment: tried run **python** as admin? because `Tesseract` may produce some temporary files, and writing to `C:\Program Files\ ` folder needs admin permission.

Comment: My Python Version is: 3.8.12

Comment: Hi, I uninstalled and reinstalled with run as admin option  I am still getting the same error

OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: it doesn't matter how you install, but how you run. right click `cmd` and run as admin, then run python commands there. if you're using some ide, then you'll need start that ide as admin.